# Why does Process.Start("cmd.exe", process); not work?

Tags: c#, .net, command-line

This works:

```
Process.Start("control", "/name Microsoft.DevicesAndPrinters");
```

But this doesn't: (It just opens a command prompt.)

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
info.Arguments = "control /name Microsoft.DevicesAndPrinters";
Process.Start(info);
```

Why?

(Yes, I know they're not identical. But the second one "should" work.)

Comment: It works fine for me. What is your error ?

Comment: @SonerGönül No error. As I wrote - it just opens a command prompt. It should open the DevicesAndPrinters. (Do you mean it does _that_ for you?)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is because `cmd.exe` expects a `/K` switch to execute a process passed as an argument. Try the code below

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
info.Arguments = "/K control /name Microsoft.DevicesAndPrinters";
Process.Start(info);
```

EDIT: Changed to `/K` above. You can use `/C` switch if you want `cmd.exe` to close after it has run the command.

Answer (score 7):

You need a `/c` or a `/k` switch (options for `cmd.exe`) so that the command is executed. Try:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
info.Arguments = "/c control /name Microsoft.DevicesAndPrinters";
Process.Start(info);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("control");
info.Arguments = "/name Microsoft.DevicesAndPrinters";
Process.Start(info);
```

Comment: I know. But I specifically want to see the command line _and_ the result.