# c# run command not executing the command

Tags: c#, command-line, process

I want to run this:

```
string command = "echo test > test.txt";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", command);
```

It's not working, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean it is not working ?

Comment: please specify how `Its not working`

Comment: What is really trying to do?

Comment: The file does not get crated and no error message

Comment: It's not exactly a C# question. Did you try just executing an echo test and see if it works? Or any other command.

Comment: Can you provide more code, an error which is being output? It is fairly impossible to identify what is wrong with what you have provided.

Comment: Of course I tested it in command prompt

Comment: A command prompt opens up and nothing, and then the file is not crated

Comment: You need to add the /C or /K switch to your command. Check my answer to a similar question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020109/why-does-process-startcmd-exe-process-not-work/14020225#14020225

Comment: Is that how you pass parameters to cmd.exe? Sorry, not very experienced, but that might be the problem.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just creating the file but in a place you might not expect?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are missing to pass the `/C` switch to `cmd.exe` to indicate that you want to execute a command. Also notice that the command is put in double quotes:

```
string command = "/C \"echo test > test.txt\"";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", command).WaitForExit();
```

And if you don't want to see the shell window you could use the following:

```
string command = "/C \"echo test > test.txt\"";
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
{
    Arguments = command,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true
};

using (var process = Process.Start(psi))
{
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: But he [says](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020664/c-sharp-run-command-not-doing-the-command/14020720#comment19362727_14020664)

Comment: @Soner Gönül, yes, that's why he should use the `/C` switch as shown in my answer. Did you read it?

Answer (score 0):

This should sort of get you started:

```
//create your command
string cmd = string.Format(@"/c echo Hello World > mydata.txt");
//prepare how you want to execute cmd.exe
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
psi.Arguments = cmd;//<<pass in your command
//this will make echo's and any outputs accessiblen on the output stream
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
Process p = Process.Start(psi);
//read the output our command generated
string result = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```